# SSIS: Adding a int variable to SQL Query via Expression

Tags: ssis, expression

I have added a variable in SSIS and I am trying to add tha variable in my expression query. But it says `Expression cannot be evaluated` Below is my expression query. Please help if you know where I am making mistakes.

SQL Query

```
SELECT c.CustomerName, o.OrderID from  Customers c
INNER JOIN Orders o ON c.CustomerID=o.CustomerID
Inner Join OrderDetails od ON od.OrderId = o.OrderID
Inner Join Products p on p.ProductID = od.ProductID 
where ISNULL(c.IsResult,0) = 0 and o.CompanyID = @CompanyID
```

Expression Format

```
"SELECT c.CustomerName, o.OrderID from  Customers c
    INNER JOIN Orders o ON c.CustomerID=o.CustomerID
    Inner Join OrderDetails od ON od.OrderId = o.OrderID
    Inner Join Products p on p.ProductID = od.ProductID 
    where ISNULL(c.IsResult,0) = 0 and o.CompanyID ="+ @[User::intCompanyID]
```

Let me know if I am doing it right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that casting the numeric values to String or Unicode works. so maybe try

`ISNULL(c.IsResult,0) = 0 and o.CompanyID ="+ (DT_WSTR,20) @[User::intCompanyID]`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following

```
"SELECT c.CustomerName, o.OrderID from  Customers c
INNER JOIN Orders o ON c.CustomerID=o.CustomerID
Inner Join OrderDetails od ON od.OrderId = o.OrderID
Inner Join Products p on p.ProductID = od.ProductID 
where ISNULL(c.IsResult,0) = 0 and o.CompanyID = ?"
```

NOTE: The image is from a different example

[image]

Click on the "Parameters" button and you can then selected your parameter from there.

Hope this helps.